# Атака одним юнитом другого

Tags: java, android-studio, объекты

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста идеи того как реализовывается атака юнитов(дальнего боя)
То бишь стоит лучник, стреляет по движущемуся объекту, и стрела должна следовать за объектом атаки ( догонять),а  не лететь в ту точку где был изначально объект.

Comment: Постоянно направляйте вектор скорости стрелы в сторону объекта атаки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создавай объект стрелы, добавляй в него ссылку на цель и каждый тик обновляй вектор скорости в соответствии с координатами цели.